# How to stop Regex Search look ahead if keyword group is found (CLOSED)

Tags: python-2.7, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have following strings on which I need to run RE Search to extract only account ids and to avoid extracting transaction related ids -

1. Transaction ID 989898989
2. Trx no. 989898989
3. Account ID 1234567890
4. Account Number 1234567890
5. Acnt No. 1234567890
6. Account # 1234567890
7. ID 1234567890

I have created a regex to extract only account id that appear in the text like this to extract 3rd group in the regex.

```
import re
txt = <all strings from 1 to 7 one by one>
re1="(No.|#|Number|ID)(/s)(\d{10,12})"

rg = re.compile(re1,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
m = rg.search(txt)
if m:
    print m.group(3)
```

If I run this code then all INT will be extracted. But I want to stop RE search if "transaction" or "trx" word is identified in the string. I tried using negative lookahead but unable to find solution.

Solution I am expecting is all strings should print INT in code above apart from strings that have "transaction" or "trx" word in it.

I want to create a regex that if "transaction" is found then stop searching further for group existence
Something like this -

```
(?!transaction)(/s)(No.|#|Number|ID)(/s)(\d{10,12})
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

Solution - Using Conditional statement in regex

```
(transaction|trx)(?(1)|\d{3,12})
```

**Explanation** -

`(transaction|trx)` => 1st Group

`(?(1)|\d{3,12})` => 2nd Group - where `?(1)` checks whether first group was found, if not found match whatever is there after `'|'` pipe - else run whatever is before `'|'`

After that just run => `m.group()`

and it will return either number or word.

In business logic, typecast the value and check if it can be type casted to INT then great we figured out correctly if not then whatever we extracted is not INT